Thought experiment: EM fields and coils
Hello Physics Exchange,
I have been thinking a lot lately about EM fields. I thought about something the other day and wanted to check with the experts if my intuition is correct or not. I know this might be very elementary but I appreciate any input.

Circuit above is pretty ordinary. For sake of argument let's just say it is an air coil with enough turns and cross sectional area to have an appreciable and measurable inductance.
But let's say we take the negative wire and instead coil it BACK in the same direction back through the inductor like so (forgive the ugliness of the drawing - note I am NOT connecting any wires here. They are insulated and ran back in close proximity but they are not electrically connected).

How would this affect the inductance of the coil, the characteristics of the circuit, the EM field generated and so forth. Would this cancel out the effect of the coil and essentially turn it into a wire? Does there still exist the additive magnetic field seen in a coil of wire? Does anything change if we change the example to use a ferromagnetic core? Be as pedantic as you like.

This just short circuits the battery and melts the wire or the battery. Are you sure this is the circuit you intend to ask about?

Do you mean for the return wire to be electrically contacting the wire of the inductor (creating a short circuit). Or not contacting but looped around the same volume of space as the inductor? In the 2nd case you'd form a transformer.

No, the wire is insulated.
Yes the picture looks like I am connecting them together (my graphics program wouldn't let me draw it) but I am not. I am running the negative wire back through the coil in close proximity to the positive wire in the same direction.

Does "coil it BACK in the same direction back" mean that the returning wire is wound in the same direction as the original coil?

My intention was per the drawing - from the negative end of the load to the negative end of the (original) coil, in the same direction viewed from that side.
But, for sake of discussion I am interested in knowing the effect of either direction.

You've designed an air-core transformer.
Depending on the direction of the windings relative to each other, this could (assuming an equal number of turns in the two windings) either

Effectively null out the original inductance.

or

Increase the effective inductance as if you'd increased the number of turns on the same core.

It's unlikely these effects will be perfect because it's difficult to achieve low leakage in an air core transformer.
Transformers in this configuration (with magnetic cores rather than air) are commonly used as common-mode chokes to allow desired out-and-back signals through while blocking common-mode signals (current flowing the same direction in both coils) that are likely to result from and/or cause electromagnetic interference.
